# How to enter a file name into your graphics window and then read that file and display the file in a graphics window using a file menu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to enter a file name into your graphics window and then read that file and display the file in a graphics window using a file menu. When I press new another window opens to ask for a name and displays it in the main window, but I can't get the new window to open and do the rest. I have the TopLevel to open a new window, but I get `NameError: name 'TopLevel' is not defined` and can't continue from there. What can I do to make it work?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple menu")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.onNew)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

    def onNew(self):
        print("do New")
        top = TopLevel()
        Label(self, text='Enter Your Name').grid(row=0)
        e1 = Entry(self)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply that you're not defining or importing anything named `Toplevel`. The way you're importing tkinter makes this an easy problem to have.

My recommendation is to remove these statements:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

... and replace them with these:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

From then on, you have access to almost everything in the tkinter and ttk packages. You simply need to add a `tk.` or `ttk.` prefix to everything you use from those packages.

This keeps global namespace pollution at a minimum (ie: you only add two names to the global namespace), and makes your code more self-documenting.

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple menu")
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.onNew)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

    def onNew(self):
        print("do New")
        top = tk.TopLevel()
        ttk.Label(self, text='Enter Your Name').grid(row=0)
        e1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```